# Как сделать гиперссылку в слове, для бота телеграм

Tags: html, python, telegram-bot

```
bot.send_message(
    message.chat.id, 
    "1.Mr.Robot\n"
    "2.The Walking Dead\n"
    "3.Fear The Walking Dead\n"
    "4.The Walking Dead: World Beyond\n"
    "5.Breaking Bad",
    reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться языком разметки [`Markdown`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown).

***Пример:***

```py
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '[StackOverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Можешь ещё использовать HTML в качестве parse_mode и тогда пишешь вот так
`"<a href='Твоя ссылка'\>Твой текст</a\>"`